# Manually installed maven dependencies not visible in Eclipse import

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, dependency-injection

I have installed maven dependency using the command below

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=d2_lib.war   -DgroupId=com.emc.d2fs -DartifactId=d2_lib  -Dversion=1.0  -Dpackaging=war -DlocalRepositoryPath="C:\Users\kumarr23\.m2\repository"
```

I have added this dependency in my root pom.xml as below

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc.d2fs</groupId>
            <artifactId>d2_lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>

        </dependency>
```

I can see when I do maven install the jars inside my final war,
when i try importing these classes from eclipse these classes are not included, Is there some thing I am missing?

I am new to maven and i am stuck here !
please advise

Comment: If you do a `mvn dependency:tree`, does d2_lib.war show up, and what are its transitive dependencies?

Comment: i see its getting in to the tree , i ran the command using command line .I dont see any transitive dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have d2_lib.war file at the location from where you are running command or else mention the full path of d2_lib.war in command and try again , i believe with the command you specify it is not copying the war file since war file path is not defined properly , you can confirm this by checking if war file is copied to your local maven repository

mvn install:install-file  **-Dfile=d2_lib.war**   -DgroupId=com.emc.d2fs -DartifactId=d2_lib  -Dversion=1.0  -Dpackaging=war -DlocalRepositoryPath="C:\Users\kumarr23.m2\repository"

Comment: i see the war file in .m2 cache , its copied .

Comment: yes exactly, should i do any thing else from eclipse workspace to get this libraries visible ?

Comment: Try to install it without specifying -DlocalRepositoryPath="C:\Users\kumarr23\.m2\repository" of command, let it find local maven repository on its own.

Comment: If you are using Maven plugin , you can update the project.. usually it should take the dependency on its own, check if our project are building properly

Comment: Just now i tried it on my local m/c, it is working fine for me, using maven plugin i run install:install-file  -Dfile=C:\Users\temp\d2_lib.war   -DgroupId=com.emc.d2fs -DartifactId=d2_lib  -Dversion=1.0  -Dpackaging=war  this command  and added dependency it is  not giving me any problem

Comment: from eclipse if u say import you can see those classes?? let me try to install once from maven plugin in eclipse

Comment: when i do import from eclipse i see classes for jar files i am not sure about war files

Comment: ok i have installed from eclipse plugin it went successfull , let me try out

Comment: i still dont see the classes from war file (it as some 9 jars). I can see some other wars in repo getting neatly working

Answer (score 0):

There is a convention in maven that java code lives in a `.jar` file and web classes live in a `.war` file. When you include a dependency with the `war` type in your web project, maven will treat the included file as an [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html).  This basically means that maven will package the contents of the dependency into your war file, however it will not include the libraries in that war as java code the way you are looking for.

When a war file is created, if the creator also wants people to get at the java code and transitive dependencies the code is based off of, they can use the `maven-war-plugin` to set a configuration tag of `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>`.  This will generate an additional artifact in the form of **artifactId-version-classes.jar**, along with the normal **artifactId-version.war** file.

When you include both the war as an overlay and the classes jar as a normal dependency, you will be able to see in your dependency tree that maven is only pulling in transitive dependencies from the jar file dependency, not the war.

In your case, you need to find the **classes** jar file and install it along with the war file in your local maven repository.  Then you can add the **classes** jar to your pom.xml like so:

### old pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.emc.d2fs</groupId>
  <artifactId>d2_lib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>war</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

### new pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.emc.d2fs</groupId>
  <artifactId>d2_lib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>war</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.emc.d2fs</groupId>
  <artifactId>d2_lib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I get an error saying misssing artifact com.emc.d2fs:d2_lib:war:classes:1.0 , i should do anything other than installing my war ?sorry for being naive .I have created my war using jar command , purpose was to get all jars under one file .

Comment: Ah, well that's your problem then.  war files are web archives.  They are for holding web content, and weren't designed to just be a wrapper around jar files.  You need to add all your jar files to a single jar.

Comment: Run the command you used to create your war file, but make it a jar file instead.

Comment: my bad! let me try that

Comment: i tried doing that and installed the jar file in local repository , added the dependency in one of modules as below                     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc.d2fs</groupId>
            <artifactId>d2_lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
   no luck still ,,.:(